# Unable to load image in opengl

Tags: java, opengl

This is my class `SimpleBox`.
I am only getting the square texture and not the image.
I have read in many websites that the size of the image should be in the powers of 2, the size of the image I am using is also in the powers of 2 still I am not able to get the image.

**Where am I going wrong?**

```
public class SimpleBox {
    private FloatBuffer box,normal;
    //private ByteBuffer bitimage;
    //private FloatBuffer normals;
    int[] textures = new int[1];
    private float[] vertices={
            -10.0f,  10.0f,  0.0f,        
            -10.0f, -10.0f,  0.0f,        
             10.0f, -10.0f,  0.0f,10.0f,  10.0f,  0.0f }; 
    private float[] normals={
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f         
            }; 
    private float textureCoordinates[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 
              0.0f, 1.0f,
              1.0f, 1.0f,
              1.0f, 0.0f };

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    public SimpleBox(Context context) {
        bitmap =getBitmapFromAsset(context ,"images/pic4.jpg" ) ;
        box = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(textureCoordinates);
        vertexBuffer=GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(vertices);
        normal=GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(normals);
    }


    public final void draw(GL10 gl) {   
        try{
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, box);
        gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, normal);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length/3);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String filePath) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        InputStream istr;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(filePath);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't specified texture internal format in `GLUtils.texImage2D` call. It should be e.g. `GL_RGB`.
2. You creating texture on each `draw` call, but after first call bitmap wouldn't be valid any longer (`bitmap.recycle();`).
3. You creating texture on each `draw` call, but never deleting it. It is very likely that after some time you'll go out of memory.

In short, move texture creation out of `draw` and correct its internal format.

Comment: To add to this, the texture is also unbound before the draw call.

Comment: @Keltar - Thanks for your advice. After making the changes you specified the texture itself is not displaying                 (GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, bitmap, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0 );)

Comment: 2Reto Koradi - Thanks

Comment: @Keltar- How to check whether the bitmap image is loaded to texture? I used glGetError() and the return status was zero. Is there any other way to check fot this?

Comment: @ShashankSegu `glGetTexImage` can be used to readback and verify texture texels. Or one of GL debuggers. But it is very unlikely to be your problem. What's `glGetError` after the draw function? What's your current code (don't replace old one, just add it to question's tail)?

Comment: @Keltar-I found that the method I am using is not working properly. I got to know this by commenting the method "glGetTexImage" and running the application. The result was same as running the application without commenting the method. The value of glGetError after the draw function is 0. I think it does not matter because the draw function is performing its task of drawing perfectly. Can you suggest other function that performs the mapping of image to the texture?

Comment: @ShashankSegu sorry I don't understand you. What doesn't work correctly? Your `GLUtils.texImage2D`? I'd be surprised by that, but if that's the case - well, use `glTexImage2D` directly then.

Comment: @Keltar- I got to know where I was going wrong. I was binding the texture with "0" after the bitmap has been loaded to that texture. Hence, I was getting the black texture. Thanks for the help Keltar :)

Comment: @ShashankSegu that's exactly what Reto Koradi said in comment. You thanked him so I was sure it is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know where I was going wrong. I was binding the texture with "0" after the bitmap has been loaded to that texture. Hence, I was getting the black texture. After commenting this I got the texture with the image.

Comment: I hope you didn't spend 2 days tracking that down. I pointed it out in my comment under the other answer.